# How to connect GoogleEarth Api by Python

Tags: python, google-earth

I am trying to connect the API by win32.com,here is the code:

```
import win32com.client

ge =  win32com.client.Dispatch('GoogleEarth.Application')
```

but get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
        IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python34/GEtest6.py", line 3, in <module>
    ge =  win32com.client.Dispatch('GoogleEarth.Application')
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

I have tried it for a long time and many ways have been used but never work.It’s really make me crazy.My friend has made a Google Earth APP using MFC by VS2010.So I want to know if there is any way to connect GE API by Python...

Comment: "*Google Earth 5.2 client will be the last version that supports the COM API. Earth 5.2 and older clients will continue to support the COM API while these versions are supported. Future releases will no longer have COM API bindings.*" - https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2010/08/sunset-for-google-earth-com-api.html

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thx,I'll try....